# Nodemon not restarting: [nodemon] restarting due to changes

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Nodemon not restarting: [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
i use vs code if change my code but not update my code browser and show restarting use due to change loop

probelm:

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
server is running at http://127.0.0.1:3000
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

my code:

```js
const http = require("http");
const PORT = 3000;
const hostName = "127.0.0.1";
const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    res.end("Welco my server  server");
})
server.listen(PORT,hostName, () => {
    console.log(`server is running at http://${hostName}:${PORT}`)
})
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test 1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.9"
  }
}
```

nodemon --verbos index.js

```
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node --verbos index.js`
node: bad option: --verbos
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: I'm guessing your a fellow windows user, whom recently updating the OS cos it looks like whatever was in that update caused me to have the same issue as you with nodemon

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a very technical fix but I managed to get my `nodemon` working as expected again.

First I ran `npm cache verify` which took a long time to run so I cleaned the cache by using `npm cache clean --force`, had to use the `--force` flag because npm will tell you there is no need to run the `cache clean` command as npm self cleans.

Then I just ran `npm i nodemon@1.19.4 -g`, the last stable build before `nodemon version 2`. Ran my `npm run dev` script and now all is well in the developer experience again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add hostname in the server.listen method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after adding the system path in the environment "C:\Windows\system32;", it still appeared. But I recognized it seems in some first nodemon run. Try to save more will get the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1 - uninstalling and reinstalling

2 `npm file.js --delay`

But what really works for me is adding
adding path of my `environmental variable` to
`C:\Windows\System32`

Steps:

Advanced system setting ->environmental variable -> Path -> edit ->`C:\Windows\System32`